# Does SQL Merge statement require BEGIN TRANS/COMITT TRAN

Tags: sql, error-handling, sql-merge

If a transaction handling is required, how do we do it for below SQL and how do we ROLLBACK

```
MERGE INTO AeoiSdtTemp AS t
USING (SELECT statusE, statusF, statusG, statusH, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy, statusI, statusJ, Email, Mobile, HomePhone, WorkPhone, statusK, statusL, Dob 
FROM [DST].[SD].[TEST_KB_KTA].[vw_SDT_TEST_KB_CGSE_Temp]) AS s ON ( t.statusE = s.statusE) AND (t.statusF = s.statusF) AND (t.statusG = s.statusG) AND (t.statusH = s.statusH)

/*** Insert records directly into local KTA table ***/
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (statusE, statusF, statusG, statusH, LastModifiedDate, StatusCode, LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy, CreatedDate, statusI, statusJ, Email, Mobile, HomePhone, WorkPhone, statusK, statusL, Dob)
VALUES(s.statusE, s.statusF, s.statusG, s.statusH, s.LastModifiedDate, '11', s.LastModifiedBy, s.LastReviewedBy, GETDATE(), s.statusI, s.statusJ, s.Email, s.Mobile, s.HomePhone, s.WorkPhone, s.statusK, s.statusL, s.Dob)

/*** Update records that exist ***/
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET LastModifiedDate = s.LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy = s.LastModifiedBy, LastReviewedBy = s.LastReviewedBy, statusI = s.statusI, statusJ = s.statusJ, Email = s.Email, Mobile = s.Mobile, HomePhone = s.HomePhone, WorkPhone = s.WorkPhone, statusK = s.statusK, statusL = s.statusL, Dob = s.Dob;
```

Comment: merge has lots of subtleties. avoid if you can!

Comment: Just disable autocommit in your client application and do the rollback command instead of commit just after the merge.